# How to use the Markers which represents the values of the places in the form of bar chart in google map?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi im  planning to  make a google map  which consists of markers which  represents some particular  places with  its values in form  of bar chart ....

And here is my  index page

--index.html--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Google Maps with AngularJS - jsFiddle demo</title>


  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    #map {
    height:420px;
    width:600px;
}
.infoWindowContent {
    font-size:  14px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h2 {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
  </style>
<body ng-app="mainctlr" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div id="map1" google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}"></div>

<div id="map"></div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>

angular.module('mainctlr', ['googlechart']).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {


   var cities = [
    {
        city : 'Toronto',
        desc : 'HTML for marker one',
        lat : 43.7000,
        long : -79.4000,

    },
    {
        city : 'New York',
        desc : 'HTML for marker two',
        lat : 40.6700,
        long : -73.9400
    },
    {
        city : 'Chicago',
        desc : 'HTML for marker three',
        lat : 41.8819,
        long : -87.6278
    },
    {
        city : 'Los Angeles&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=3333.png />',
        desc : 'HTML for marker four',
        lat : 34.0500,
        long : -118.2500
    },
    {
        city : 'Las Vegas',
        desc : 'HTML for marker five',
        lat : 36.0800,
        long : -115.1522
    }
];


    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.cssStyle = "height:200px; width:300px;";
    chart1.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "month", label: "Month", type: "string"},
        {id: "laptop-id", label: "Laptop", type: "number"},
        {id: "desktop-id", label: "Desktop", type: "number"},
        {id: "server-id", label: "Server", type: "number"},
        {id: "cost-id", label: "Shipping", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "1"},
            {v: 19, f: "42 items"},
            {v: 12, f: "Ony 12 items"},
            {v: 7, f: "7 servers"},
            {v: 4}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "2"},
            {v: 13},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "1"},
            {v: 24},
            {v: 0},
            {v: 11},
            {v: 6}

        ]},

       {c: [
            {v: "2"},
            {v: 19},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "1"},
            {v: 13},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]},
         {c: [
            {v: "2"},
            {v: 24},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "1"},
            {v: 19},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "2"},
            {v: 13},
            {v: 1, f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"},
            {v: 12},
            {v: 2}
        ]}
    ]};

    chart1.options = {
        "isStacked": "true",
        "fill": 20,
        "displayExactValues": true
    };

    chart1.formatters = {};

    $scope.chart = chart1;


    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long,info.chart),
            title: info.city,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content + marker.chart);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }  

    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        createMarker(cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    } 


});





   </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

And this is the present  output  of mine .

[image]

When you  click on  the markers which  is present  on  the map  it displays with  some text  information

but my  plan  is to  display  the bar chart in it only when  i  click the particular marker which appear inside the popup.

Here is the example image  which  i'm exactly  looking for :-

[image]

And here is my plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/YNkmSXLmQt0c7eqKhpi8?p=preview

And these are my  goal  to  be achieved  and got  stuck with  the bar chart.
So please  help  me with  this . And thanks  in advance

Answer (score 1):

Prepare HTML for every marker and add the respective HTML into

`desc` key of every marker.

like :

```
var cities = [
    {
        city : 'Toronto',
        desc : 'HTML for marker one',
        lat : 43.7000,
        long : -79.4000
    },
    {
        city : 'New York',
        desc : 'HTML for marker two',
        lat : 40.6700,
        long : -73.9400
    },
    {
        city : 'Chicago',
        desc : 'HTML for marker three',
        lat : 41.8819,
        long : -87.6278
    },
    {
        city : 'Los Angeles&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=3333.png />',
        desc : 'HTML for marker four',
        lat : 34.0500,
        long : -118.2500
    },
    {
        city : 'Las Vegas',
        desc : 'HTML for marker five',
        lat : 36.0800,
        long : -115.1522
    }
];
```

Comment: But  my  question  is how to  use the bar  chart  when  i  click  on the marker

Comment: Once i  click  the marker the simple bar chart  with  some example values should appear . How can i do that?

Comment: Yes, Your bar chart is an HTML on webpage. You can use HTML of your bar chart in 'desc' field of marker and that will be visible on click of that particular marker

Comment: i have progressed a bit more further following your advice. I have equally updated the plunker source code. Could u please help me